# How to filter by some elements in Object?

Tags: angularjs

I use `filter` in `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (campaign.data.issues | filter:filters) | orderBy : 'created_at'">
```

Where `filters`is object:

```
$scope.filters = {status : "active"};
```

I tried to use complicated object for sorting by each status:

```
 $scope.filters = [{status : "active"}, {status : "paused"}, {status : "finished"}];
```

But it does not work

I know simple solution to use login negation:

```
$scope.filters = {status : !"active"};
```

But I dont know how to use negation object in filter

Comment: I don't understand what you are exactly trying to achieve

Comment: If you're trying to filter your array by the status of property, why don't you just pass the status property to your filter, instead of doing it with the full object? Should be something like this


`<tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (campaign.data.issues | filter:filters.status) | orderBy : 'created_at'">`